# Lower the voltage

Tags: voltage, components

I need to lower the voltage of [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000WJX4BQ) 12v battery to power [this](http://microcontrollershop.com/product_info.php?products_id=5314) board, what parts do I need?

Sorry, for more naive questions just another programmer =)

Comment: The board says "6V to 16V DC input power supply, noise-immune design". Why do you need to lower it? Sounds like you just need some wire.

Comment: I am not hesitant to wire things together!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can power it directly with 12V - according to the specs in the link you give, it has a 6V-16V input range.
Looking at the schematic (p.32 of the [datasheet](http://pub.ucpros.com/download/A13-OLINUXINO-revision_D.pdf?osCsid=es6eqnc84m4tto2c336cjjk670)) confirms that it uses a [MP1482DS](http://www.monolithicpower.com/Page/DownLoad.aspx?ListID=1a4312a6-2709-4b7d-af52-9f1cedbfd415&&ItemID=97) buck regulator, so efficiency will be good over the entire range (as opposed to a linear regulator which will become more inefficient at higher voltages)